Convert decimal format duration in hours (xx.xx) to time format duration (hh:mm:ss)
The below table subset is calculated from this Table.AddColumn formula I received from a previous post:
each Duration.From(([#"Duration,h"])*#duration(0,1,0,0))




Turbo Config
Fuel Injection,°
Speed,rpm
Duration,h
Duration




L1
30
400
0.08
0.00:04:48


L1
30
450
1.31
0.01:18:36


L1
30
500
92
3.20:00:00


L1
30
520
73.55
3.01:33:00


L1
30
540
13.56
0.13:33:36


L1
30
560
7.68
0.07:40:48


L1
30
580
9.18
0.09:10:48


L1
30
600
18.29
0.18:17:24


L1
30
620
7.06
0.07:03:36


L1
30
640
0.17
0.00:10:12


L1
30
660
0.21
0.00:12:36


L1
30
680
0.07
0.00:04:12



Some of the results aren't making much sense. What are some adjustments to the function that I can make?

how would you do the calculation using a calculator, pen and paper?

Which ones do not make sense?
